# UIView subclass thinks its a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, iboutlet

Having a crazy issue today. I created a UIView sublcass:

```
@interface MyNavBar : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;

- (void)updateTitle:(NSString*)title;

@end
```

If I place the cursor in the "MyNavBar" text, I get this in the help view:

```
UITabBarController manages a button bar and transition view, for an application with multiple top-level modes....
```

WTH?

What's worse, I created a UIView in the storyboard and assigned it as class MyNavBar. I created a UILabel as a subview, but I can't drag it to hook it up as the titleLabel. Nor can I create a new IBOutlet in the interface by dragging from IB.

Nowhere in the process did I do anything that has to do with a UITabBarController. What could be going on here?

I'm running Xcode 6 GM.

Comment: If you can reproduce it then file a bug report.

Comment: Probably just a documentation bug.

Comment: It's much worse than a documentation bug. I cannot connect any Outlets, which means I can't build the user interface.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but got somewhat different results (using Xcode Version 6.0 (6A267n)). I do get the wrong help message, but I was able to connect the label by right clicking on MyNavBar in the scene list, choosing the outlet I had created, and dragging to the label. It didn't let me drag from the label to the .h file to create a new outlet though.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround tip!

Answer (score 1):

(This isn't really an answer so much as an update)

It may be a problem with the way information for Swift classes was generated. In Xcode 7.2 I just used "Jump to Definition" on a UIImage function.  Right above the class declaration was a comment block identical to the one in UITabBarController.h.  (I put the whole block in the search field and it found UITabBarController.h.)

After I found this article in a search, I checked "Jump to Definition" for UIView.  This block is still above the definitions for UIView as well.

```
/*!
 UITabBarController manages a button bar and transition view, for an application with multiple top-level modes.

 To use in your application, add its view to the view hierarchy, then add top-level view controllers in order.
 Most clients will not need to subclass UITabBarController.

 If more than five view controllers are added to a tab bar controller, only the first four will display.
 The rest will be accessible under an automatically generated More item.

 UITabBarController is rotatable if all of its view controllers are rotatable.
 */
@available(iOS 2.0, *)
public class UIImage : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
```